# Writing an array to a textfile from a textArea in java

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, jtextarea

I'm new to Java and I am trying to write what I have in a text area called AreaBooking into a textfile. I can get it to write to the textfile but just cant get them on separate lines. I may also have a lot of redundant code but I don't know as I said I'm new to this language.

I want it like

```
1
2
3
```

and not 1,2,3

```
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    AreaBooking.replaceSelection("");      

    String s[] = AreaBooking.getText().split("\n");
    ArrayList<String>arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s)) ;
    System.out.println(arrList);


    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_name)));
        out.write(AreaBooking.getText());
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    out.write(AreaBooking.getText());
```

write:

```
for (String s : arrList) {
    out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JTextArea#write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)) instead.

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new WriterReader("Inventory.txt"))) {
    textArea.write(writer);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```